# "Recursive" grouping in MongoDB - is it possible?

Tags: mongodb

There is a MongoDB database with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "code": "E1F417C68D71",
    "names": [ <-- e.g. taxonomy in strict order from regnum to species
      { 
        "idx": 0,
        "type": "Level 0 name"
      },
      {
        "idx": 1,
        "type": "Level 1 name"
      },
      {
        "idx": 2,
        "type": "..."
      },
      etc...
    ]
  },
  "duplicatesCount": ? <- some integer
},
{
  "_id": {
    "code": "E1F238D90A06",
    "names": [ 
      { 
        "idx": 0,
        "type": "Level 0 other name"
      },
      {
        "idx": 1,
        "type": "Level 1 name"
      },
      {
        "idx": 2,
        "type": "..."
      },
      etc...
    ]
  },
  "duplicatesCount": ?
},
```

I would like to get the following document on the output:

```
[{
  "type": "Level 0 name",
  "duplicatesCount": ?
  "childs": [{
    "type": "Level 1 name",
    "duplicatesCount": ?,
    {
      ...
        { <- at the very end of the tree
          "type": "Level end name",
          "duplicatesCount": ?,
          "code": "***" <- This field appears here
          "childs": []
        }
    }
  },
  {
    ...
  }]
},
{
  "type": "Level 0 other name",
  "duplicatesCount": ?
  "childs": [{ ... }]
},
etc...

]
```

The problem is that I can't figure out if this is even possible with MongoDB?

One solution I can think of is not to use MongoDB syntax directly. But let's suppose to group all elements by idx = 0 first, write it down somewhere.

Then for each "group" group by idx = 2... and so on.

But I'm afraid that such a process would contain a huge number of cycles, which would take a lot of time.

I can imagine how to group documents by idx = 0:

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { 
    "$group": { 
      "_id" : { 
        "name_idx_0": { "$first": "$_id.names" }  
      }, 
      "duplicatesCount": { "$sum": 1 },
      "codes": { "$push": "$_id.code" }
    }
  },
], 
{ 
  allowDiskUse: true 
});
```

Then the result is something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "name_idx_0": {
        "idx": 0,
        "type": "Level 0 name"
      }
    },
    "duplicatesCount": 70,
    "codes": [
      "code 1",
      "code 2", etc...
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "name_idx_0": {
        "idx": 0,
        "type": "Level 0 other name"
      }
    },
    "duplicatesCount": 63,
    "codes": [
      "code 1",
      "code 3", etc...
    ]
  },
  etc...
]
```

But how to create a group in a group to continue grouping, gradually deepening I can not think of anything.

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting your goal as basically a reorganization of *all* the data from a set of `{name: [ hier0, hier1, hier2, ... ]}` to a tree (actually a forest) of `hier0`?    If so, you're not taking advantage of the DB engine for anything and you're still pulling all the data across the wire.   Thus:   Make it easy on yourself (and others) and just do a `find()`, drag back everything, and use `maps` and `dict` or similar in your client code.

Comment: The data model (_"document structure"_) is very curious.  What does `"duplicatesCount"` mean in the shown documents?  Are `"code"` values unique per document?

Comment: @rickhg12hs in fact, the document I cited is a grouping by value of "code" and "names". "duplicatesCount" is the value of repetitions of such data before grouping. The data now stored in the database is unique in two fields, "code" and "names". The interest now is to regroup the data so that "code" is at the very end (depth) of the tree.

The data stored in "names" is actually a structure describing the path in the tree, which eventually comes to "code".

Comment: @rickhg12hs The point is that each "code" can have only one path. That is, it should not be, for example, that idx = 0, 1 and 3 are the same, but idx = 2 is different. It is interesting just to find such anomalies.

Ultimately, I see this as the fact that "code" will be in different branches of the tree. That is, two completely identical children, can't have different parents, but one parent can have many children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this challenge before and decided to refine my solution into something more generic.  As I mentioned in the question comments, there is no practical reason to make the DB engine itself do any grouping because we are not actually doing any aggregation; we are just reorganizing.  All the data is still coming across the wire.  It is possible of course to use `$match` and `$project` to reduce the population being reorganized; *that* is useful.

```js
/**
 *  flatToHierarchy
 *  Consume data with a given hierarchy of string keys and produce an output
 *  structure that recursively groups the next level in the hierarchy and
 *  optionally terminates the cascade with a value (scalar or object) of your
 *  choice.  Neither the hierarchy nor the terminal value need to be unique.
 *  Example:
 *
 *    var data = [
 *      {hierarchy:["K1","P1","S1"], udef: "label1"},
 *      {hierarchy:["K1","P1","S1"], udef: {whatever:"2"}},
 *      {hierarchy:["K1","P1","S2"], udef: "label2"},
 *      {hierarchy:["K2","P1","S6"], udef: "label3"},
 *      {hierarchy:["K2","P2","S7"], udef: "label4"}
 *   ];
 *   
 *  ff = flatToHierarchy();
 *  for (const item of data) {
  *    ff.addData(item['hierarchy'],item['udef']);
 *  }
 *  print(ff.getHierarchy());
 *
 *  [
 *    {"K1": [
 *      {"P1": [
 *        {"S1": [ "label1", {whatever:"2"} ]},
 *        {"S2": [ "label2" ]}    
 *      ]}
 *    ]},
 *    {"K2": [
 *      {"P1": [
 *        {"S6": [ "label3" ]}
 *      ]},
 *      {"P2": [
 *        {"S7": [ "label4" ]}
 *      ]}, 
 *  ]
 *
 *  The order of the keys in the array at each level is determined by the
 *  order in which the key is first seen when calling addData().
 */
function flatToHierarchy() {
    const forest = [];

    function _buildTree(node, hierarchy, udef) {
        if (hierarchy.length === 0) {
            if(udef != null) {
                node.push(udef);
            }
            return;
        }

        var level = hierarchy.shift();
        let child = node.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(level));

        if (!child) {
            child = {};
            child[level] = [];
            node.push(child);
        }

        _buildTree(child[level], hierarchy, udef);
    }

    function addData(slist, udef=null) {
        const hierarchy = slist.slice();
        root = forest.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(hierarchy[0]));

        if (!root) {
            var newRoot = {};
            newRoot[hierarchy[0]] = [];
            forest.push(newRoot);
            root = newRoot;
        }
        _buildTree(root[hierarchy[0]], hierarchy.slice(1), udef);
    }

    function getHierarchy() {
        return forest;
    }
    
    return { addData, getHierarchy };
}

const ff = flatToHierarchy();

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    // Optional $match here to reduce input set, e.g.
    /*
    {$match: {$expr: {
        $eq: [ {$arrayElemAt: ["$names.type", 0]}, "Level 0 name" ]
    }}},
    */
    
    // flatToHierarchy wants an array of string keys.  This also reduces the
    // amount of material coming across (single string instead of object which
    // in the OP example has a redundant idx field but there could be others): 
    {$project: {
        code: true,
        names: {$map: {input: "$names", in: "$$this.type"}}
        }}

]);

while(c.hasNext()) {
    doc = c.next();
    uname = doc['code'];
    slist = doc['names'];
    ff.addData(slist, uname);
}
printjson(ff.getHierarchy());
```